# String to date conversion in c# as yyyy/mm/dd

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I would like convert string content to date format as `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss tt`

```
string date = "2014-11-20 3:21:00 PM";
DateTime date_=System.DateTime.Now;

var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss tt", 
                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,
                                    out date_);
```

But it returns result doesn't match requirement also `TryParse` function return false. If time zone is not defined, it will return expected result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`HH` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#HH_Specifier) is for *24 hour clock* which is `00` to `23`.

You need to use [`h` specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#hSpecifier) instead which represents `1` to `12` in *12 hour clock*.

Also you don't need to initialize your [`out` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx) value. Definition will be enough like;

```
string date = "2014-11-20 3:21:00 PM";
DateTime date_;

var result = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss tt",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                    DateTimeStyles.None, out date_);
```

Answer (score -1):

The DateTime data type format is always MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt (i.e. Date = {11/20/2014 12:00:00 AM}),
If you want to display the value you can change the format by using ToString extention method

Comment: That's wrong. A `DateTime` doesn't have _any_ implicit format. It has just date and time values. String representations of them can have formats. It doesn't have any `DateTime`. That's why he can't use `ToString` method. He doesn't want to format his datetime, he wants to parse it's string to datetime.

Comment: And `DateTime.ToString()` is not an extension method. It is a `DateTime` method.